# How to change color to a link in div?

Tags: css

I've created (copied and edited from online tool) a little box with a text [here on the botton right corner](http://www.lopsicoterapeuta.it)

I would like to change also the color of the text in the box. But there's the command a:link, a:visited.

How could I bypass these commands and giving the color I would like to to the text, maintaining the link?

Thanks

Comment: You can avoid :link and :visited by doing this to .button class: `.button { color: #28a26b !important; }` Or you can also override :link and :visited selectors.

Comment: And isn't it a good idea just to change :link and :visited selectors with color you want?

Comment: I am in agreement with Yura Yakym :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-selectors as a:link and a:hover (and many more) change the default behavior of the browser. You may omit them, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to.

a:link sets style of the anchor so it is not the default blue underlined.

a:hover sets style of the anchor when you move your mouse over the link.

Use search engine of your choice to learn more, try 'css pseudo selector'

Read the code, the color settings are all there:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;  
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 12px 24px; 
    border: 1px solid #28A26B;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: transparent 
            linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF, #FFF)
            repeat scroll 0% 0%; 
            // this is what you're probably 
            // looking for - the color of the button body.
            // It's set to transparent.
    font: bold 20px arial;
    color: #28A26B;  // Color of the content
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
    // these pseudo classes just make the js events onmouseover
    // and onclick obsolete...
    color: #28A26B; 
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

Set background to the color of your choice, remove the gradient part and you're done. Do NOT copy blindly.

Answer (score 0):

After rule on line 77 of styles.css file put this one:

```
#call-to-action a:link, #call-to-action a:visited {
    color:yellow ;
}
```